# Why doesn't Kaddish include Hashem's name?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, kaddish

Why doesn't Kaddish, *a prayer for the sanctification of God's name*, not include Hashem's name?

Comment: Since it is written in Aramaic, the references are indeed there.

Comment: יתגדל ויתקדש **שמיה** רבה

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia on Kiddush Hashem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiddush_Hashem) says:

> The instruction "to sanctify [God]" and the converse command "you
> shall not profane My holy name" is frequently expressed. Any action by
> a Jew that brings honour, respect, and glory to God is considered to
> be sanctification of His name.

The objective of Kaddish is to bring about the “sanctification of G-d's name”. Following Wikipedia, this can be achieved by saying the prayer of Kaddish which indeed  brings honour, respect, and glory to G-d. The actual mention of one or many of the names of G-d is not needed to achieve that.

Furthermore, [Wikipedia on Kaddish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaddish) says,

> Kaddish does not contain God's name. It is said that this is because
> Kaddish has 26 words, equalling the gematria of the Lord's name itself
> (י-ה-ו-ה), and the Kaddish text proves that from the very beginning
> with words "May His great name be exalted and sanctified".

So the Kaddish is a sanctification of the name (for which mention of the name is not necessary) and anyway the name is actually hinted at in the Kaddish.

Comment: Making a bracha with Hashem's name in it is also a kiddush Hashem. Does somebody now need to ask 'Why is Hashem's name hinted to in kaddish and not stated explicitly?'